# Inconsistent plot behaviour between geopandas/folium/leaflet and plotly

Tags: polygon, geopandas, choropleth, plotly

I need to plot an interactive map of German postal code regions. For this I would like to employ a plotly.express.choropleth map. For roughly ~7500 of the 8300 regions this works like a charm. Unfortunately, for the remaining regions plotly seems to get the orientation of the polygones wrong:

[image]

The problem is, that I cannot figure out, why the plot turns out wrong in plotly. I have checked the orientation of the edges (with the orientation being consistent across all 8300 regions):

[image]

I have verified, that the centroid of the region (as computed by geopandas) is within Germany (as opposed to the opposite side of the world): postal_codes.geometry.centroid = **POINT (6.25030 51.31646)**.

Also, I have plotted the same region using geopandas.DataFrama.explore():

[image]

Any ideas anybody? :(

You can load the shape of the polygone that's depicted above as geojson:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"id": "4753", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"region_id": "41334"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.25759159551657, 51.3620329779054], [6.22674617205239, 51.365633164072], [6.22444872249862, 51.3649704207859], [6.22631894075279, 51.3605546143711], [6.1899070071525, 51.3394543938591], [6.19426159278685, 51.3348703440469], [6.1854202733527, 51.3346546140994], [6.17416028291703, 51.3330495494914], [6.16858422038773, 51.3329795447041], [6.16936418645312, 51.3293300166974], [6.16211652019435, 51.3230115842556], [6.15961744170531, 51.3196839261837], [6.15917056389077, 51.3154065142613], [6.15426110832449, 51.3109674787698], [6.15383279603901, 51.3074261455405], [6.17383815212283, 51.3003487293762], [6.17826982198397, 51.3021528124584], [6.18005353204891, 51.3017348540289], [6.18873819935719, 51.3027310873733], [6.19079932638695, 51.3002635519086], [6.19843397820144, 51.3023234558051], [6.2017794022204, 51.3010566429582], [6.21128147917417, 51.2947831765034], [6.2213423450626, 51.2857902474551], [6.22830596276523, 51.2806888925787], [6.23179209968684, 51.279350402822], [6.23433813212753, 51.2787827884543], [6.23353204822973, 51.2749297921029], [6.23268632856096, 51.2742319651821], [6.23473508555356, 51.2721932856899], [6.22866667329171, 51.2707815486825], [6.2346831900953, 51.2600263653457], [6.23616193999372, 51.2602845313032], [6.23861139422953, 51.2559467892672], [6.24142456838164, 51.2528049983325], [6.24651851073767, 51.2553575821283], [6.25009725384023, 51.2591981690455], [6.25430399589004, 51.2589534668074], [6.25686092488099, 51.2627175133241], [6.26411741903873, 51.2683911852773], [6.26592948949606, 51.272031139355], [6.26567669040929, 51.2758732586984], [6.26851021220286, 51.2796987146605], [6.27306996325305, 51.2788838585939], [6.27622052433243, 51.2843637337508], [6.30452081830391, 51.2775340580964], [6.31826906487104, 51.2772117641171], [6.32655814718194, 51.2778054169968], [6.32147959082357, 51.2862362324667], [6.3142731355951, 51.2863568477585], [6.31378780683609, 51.2933427551957], [6.3186814029799, 51.2930910489484], [6.32139755912665, 51.2976662079215], [6.31957871994332, 51.2981619580872], [6.32192835004979, 51.301587366345], [6.32066748731514, 51.3028071216022], [6.32113823139307, 51.3040496209346], [6.31834955835255, 51.3047188064445], [6.3214269180918, 51.3085053811113], [6.31890121121731, 51.312710728004], [6.31908168009925, 51.3139146874175], [6.31656345773863, 51.3148994633353], [6.31496276155627, 51.3177144912525], [6.31417286165014, 51.3179500168611], [6.31417918154349, 51.3217208514643], [6.31624500935491, 51.3222825408531], [6.31329971055241, 51.3241375954849], [6.31699157135774, 51.3254929804933], [6.3157313640447, 51.3290021495174], [6.31969641993732, 51.3293730670889], [6.31956101358546, 51.3323898521365], [6.31112299126933, 51.3334316948908], [6.31194435773355, 51.3349872817138], [6.31071378024246, 51.3363031348685], [6.3133432413171, 51.3363966743481], [6.3127517023639, 51.3395508758328], [6.3140233734103, 51.3401620005886], [6.31311844768588, 51.3457156599413], [6.3079361042153, 51.3532437135755], [6.31004589884257, 51.3543366739173], [6.30545761338133, 51.3579987281457], [6.30409165649909, 51.3579690832902], [6.30406776111985, 51.3599942227126], [6.28530005741198, 51.3595334155322], [6.28298643865312, 51.3584229525221], [6.28228594007486, 51.3582996009249], [6.28172483420492, 51.3580098360699], [6.26580932581206, 51.3549486000478], [6.26313461419479, 51.3564085456764], [6.2638262513051, 51.3566566167129], [6.25759159551657, 51.3620329779054]]]}}]}
```

Edit: Also tried plotting the polygon in [DataStudio](https://datasciencecampus.github.io/creating-choropleth-maps-in-google-data-studio/) - same result as with plotly. The geometry was created using [BigQuery ST_GEOGFROMTEXT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_geogfromtext), which per default will create the polygon of the smallest shape. So no idea, why plotly and DataStudio still get it wrong.

Edit: You can reproduce the issue using the following code. Suppose the geojson string is saved in 'sample.geojson', then run:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px

# read data
postal_codes = gpd.read_file("sample.geojson")

# plotly get polygon orientation wrong
fig = px.choropleth(
    postal_codes,
    geojson=json.loads(postal_codes.to_json()),
    locations="region_id",
    featureidkey="properties.region_id",
)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.show()

# geopandas gets it right
postal_codes_sample.explore()

# polygon orientation is correct
geojson = postal_codes.to_json()
polygon = json.loads(geojson)['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']
points = []
z = 0
for i in polygon[0]:
    if z % 2 == 1:
        points.append(i)
    z += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(points, columns=["lon", "lat"])
ax = df.plot(x="lon", y="lat", kind="scatter")
for i, point in enumerate(points):
    ax.text(point[0], point[1]+0.005, str(i))
```

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you include a code example reproducing the issue.